# Q: Laravel 8 - images don't show on production server

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have shared my Laravel project, but the images don't show on the production. On the other hand, the project is working perfectly locally, but I faced a problem when I want to run `php artisan storage:link` on the server in order to show images.

Server OS:Linux GNU/Linux

PHP version : 7.4

Laravel version: 8

```
yf*******@sg3pl***** [~/a***]$ php artisan storage:link

   ErrorException

  symlink(): No such file or directory

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:315
    311▕      */
    312▕     public function link($target, $link)
    313▕     {
    314▕         if (! windows_os()) {
  ➜ 315▕             return symlink($target, $link);
    316▕         }
    317▕
    318▕         $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    319▕

      +15 vendor frames
  16  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure your account has the permission to create a symlink in ./public directory

Comment: I have the permission.

Comment: I think my mistake was the public file was in the public_html, so the public folder must be in the same project's folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solving this issue. 
I was wrong, for I deleted the public folder from my project. Moreover, when I deleted the public folder from my project folder, I couldn’t link a storage folder, so I should keep the public file in the main folder project.

=> `cd FILE_PROJECT` in the root.
=> `mkdir public` .
=> `php artisan storage:link`

This way works for me.

Answer (score 0):

My similar problem was solved by adding **FILESYSTEM_DRIVER = public** in .env, you can try this.

Comment: I don't think so because I wrote this line in my env file.